# Why does my Monodroid application run slower in a Release build than in a Debug build?

Tags: optimization, release, xamarin.android

I have a quite CPU intensive Monodroid app (multithreaded image processing, lots of floating point operations) and for some reason a release build run much slower than a debug build. Processing an image takes perhaps 7 secs in debug mode (without debugger attached) and 21 secs in release mode. Any ideas why?

The test was done with a Galaxy Tab 8.9 (1GHz dual core).

I'm using the Monodevelop environment and there is an Optimization compiler option, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Are you testing the release mode on emulator or actual device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to ensure that you've included the armeabi-v7a runtime in your package.  There should be an option somewhere in your project properties.